# Polymorphism, why can't I do this?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism

```
class BaseA
{
}

class B : public BaseA
{
}

template <class T>
class C : public vector<T>
{
}

void someFunction (void)
{
    C<B> myClass;

    // I can't seem to do this...is it not possible?
    vector<BaseA> converted = ((vector<BaseA>) myClass);
}
```

See comment in code for what I am trying to do.

Comment: For starters, there is no A class

Comment: @SLaks not really a problem here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Why not? It looks like he's trying to convert a `vector<B>` to a `vector<BaseA>`

Comment: List<A> has no (inheritance) relationship to List<B> regardless of (inheritance) relationship between A and B.

Comment: @SLaks because `vector<A>` holds copies. There's nothing wrong with this conversion, other than the fact that it happens to not be defined in `std::vector`, and slicing may happen.

Comment: I see.  This is why I generally don't answer C++ questions.  (I'm a C# guy)

Comment: Happy 120,000th C++ question SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A vector of B isn't a vector of A even if B is an A (I assume a mixup between A and BaseA)

Try

```
vector<A> converted(myClass.begin(), myClass.end());
```

which is probably what you want to express.

(BTW inheriting from vector [is bad idea in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6806173/136208), it isn't designed for that.)

Comment: This is an important point.  Inheriting from any STL container is not a good idea because they dont have virtual destructors. use the container as a member if you must.

Comment: Your proposed solution is functionally useful, but doesn't it change the desired behaviour, since now converted is a shallow copy of myClass, rather than a reference to the same vector?

Comment: @Alain Here `converted` holds deep copies of the objects in `myClass`. In the original, if it worked, `converted` would hold deep copies of the objects in `myClass`. There is no reference in the code posted.

Comment: Well the desired behavior isn't allowed (for obvious reasons). This is the closest you'll get if you ignore just casting the iterators as needed as you're parsing the array.

Comment: I see... I thought the purpose was for the two variables to point to the same object in memory. Maybe I've been doing C# for too long too.

Comment: Wait, are you sure it's a Deep copy? Surely not if `class T` doesn't have a copy constructor implemented? But maybe that's just an obvious given.

Comment: @Alain well, it doesn't compile in that case. But the classes in the example do have copy constructors (they're generated by the compiler).

Comment: @Alain, then this isn't possible. The cases when the memory layout would be compatible are rare (a subset of the cases where B doesn't add any data member to A).

Answer (score 3):

`C<B>` and `vector<A>` are completely unrelated types and you would have to explicitly define such a conversion (e.g. `template <typename TargetValueType> explicit operator vector<TargetValueType> () { ... }`).

If such conversion is an uncommon task, something that is not really natural to the nature of your class, it might be preferable to use a range constructor (see AProgrammer's answer).

Also: If `vector` is `std::vector`, deriving from it is not a good idea. It isn't defined as a base class, and typically you should prefer containment over derivation (as it imposes looser coupling on your clients).

Answer (score 0):

No way no how. Imagine if you had another class, `X`, derived from `BaseA`. If you could get your `converted` object, you could insert instances of `X` in it, even though the original object wouldn't allow it. You'd be breaking the semantics of your variables.

Incidentally you *can* do this in Java where they have no real sense of generics, but in a strongly typed generic language like C# or C++ you won't be able to do it (with the one exception in C#, but you shouldn't use it in this case anyway).

Comment: Covariance is not important here. The converted object is **a copy, holding (possibly sliced) copies of the originals**. Inserting `X`s into it works just fine (other than the fact that the `X`s will get sliced), because it doesn't insert anything in the original object.