# Inheriting from std::vector

Tags: c++

There are many answers on here saying not to inherit from std::vector and alike such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353954/potential-problems-with-inheriting-from-stdvector). I understand the reasons and agree with them. However in [here](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/4-Tour-Algo-draft.pdf) Section 4.4.1.2 Bjarne Stroustrup himself inherits from std::vector to add range checking.

Is that a special case, or just something that's ok in that context or something that he really ought not be doing :P

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup is a special case.

Comment: I think it's the easiest way to demonstrate the principles he's describing, without having to set up a complicated example class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/912144) perfectly answers your question.

It's not impossible to inherit from `std::vector`, it just probably would be very limited (due to no virtual destructor), quite confusing to others and extending by composition would be better/easier/more maintainable than inheritance anyway.

Perhaps Stroustrup simply wanted to show it's doable, but not necessarily to imply that he suggests it.

Comment: That makes sense, and you're not at all likely to use vector polymorphicly anyway..

Comment: @jcoder also note that you can achieve a lot, without most of the pitfalls, by using private inheritance.

Comment: Interestingly, Stroustrup comes back to the same example again later in his book The C++ Programming Language, in section 16.3.4, where he adds the following warning: 
 "...derivation from a concrete class should be done with care and only rarely because of the lack of virtual functions and run-time type information..." - I would summarize it as follows: it works if you know what you're doing!