# Should a user-defined container that is a wrapper for std::vector, inherit or contain std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Should a user-defined container that is a wrapper for std::vector, inherit or contain std::vector?

I have a class that is supposed to be a container. I see two options:

1) inherit from vector
2) have a private member vector and override all the vector functions to make my container act as vector

I am not sure if it is only a question of style, or one way is fundamentally better
than the other?

The extra functionality I want to add is small, few data members and functions here
and there. Mostly it will be convenient functions to work with the data in the vector.

Comment: What kind of extra functionality are you wanting to add?

Comment: What about private/protected inheritance?

Comment: @cmbasnett I edited my post, in the end.

Comment: @Xymostech Not sure what exactly you mean? Why not public inheritance from vector?

Comment: @user3111311 What kind of data members?  What are they supposed to do?  Reason I ask is because other container types may be more suitable to your needs or there may be a better alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, STL containers are not supposed to be inherited. They even don't have virtual destructors.

Second, it's always preferable to choose composition/aggregation in favor of inheritance, as this is a lower coupling technique that puts less restrictions/requirements on the code.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/419450) for more details, this question has been raised a lot of times.

Comment: "First of all, STL containers are not supposed to be inherited." after that I stopped reading. That is enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting read about this topic here - [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector)

Unlike what the title suggests, it's OK to inherit from std::vector, in the end it's more an architectural issue. Does it help reuse or code complexity? By doing that, does it make it easier to understand, maintain and debug the code?