# Why can you inherit from interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have an application that I'm porting from C++ to Java. There is a section C++ code that I find really strange.

```
typedef std::string ArgName;
typedef std::map< ArgName, AnyData > ArgumentMap;

class Arguments : public ArgumentMap
{
    public:
    // Very important note: When read finds a numeric/set argument,
    // it sets anyData.kind to Int. But STILL, it fills anyData.dString,
    // just in case. So if the ArgumentMap was built by Arguments::read,
    // the dString fields are all filled.
    bool read( int argc, char **argv );

    // remains is filled with the arguments not starting with '-'.
    bool read( int argc, char **argv, std::vector<const char*>& remains );

    // const if fails, erases arg if succeeds.
    bool getNumericParam( const ArgName& name, int& num );

    // sw is true if the switch is present. The function
    // returns false if the argument value is not empty.
    bool getSwitch( const ArgName& name, bool& sw );

    bool getSwitchConst( const ArgName& name, bool& sw ) const;

    // Returns true if the switch is present. Throws an error message if
    // if the argument value is not empty.
    bool getSwitchCompact( const ArgName& name );

    void checkEmptyArgs() const;

};
```

It looks like in there original C++ the author is making their Arguments class inherit from a Map. This makes no sense to me. Map is an interface which means you can't inherit from it, you can only implement it. Is this something that can be done in C++ that you can't do in Java?

Also, I don't understand why you would use a typedef. I read the definition from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)

> typedef is a keyword in the C and C++ programming languages. The purpose of typedef is to 
>   form complex types from more-basic machine types[1] and assign simpler names to such 
>   combinations. They are most often used when a standard declaration is cumbersome, 
>   potentially confusing, or likely to vary from one implementation to another

But I don't understand why the author would do that here. Are they trying to say that they want to inherit from the class AnyData and that ArgumentMap should have a Map as one of its fields?

Comment: On one hand, nicely written question. On the other, it would take less than half the time of writing this to check some [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for details on `std::map`.

Comment: @Xam I tried looking for something before I posted to Stackoverflow. The problem was that I was looking for the wrong thing. I'd forgotten that there are no interfaces in C++. I tried googling things about C++ and inheritance because the way I was thinking about it, this was a weird inheritance issue. It **never** would have occurred to me to look up class templates, virtual inheritance, etc. It might seem obvious for you since you know C++ well, but since I know Java better I was literally scratching my head going WTF!?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This makes no sense to me. Map is an interface

In Java, it is. In C++, it's not even a class, it is a class template. C++ does not have a concept similar to Java's interfaces, although you can implement something similar with virtual inheritance.

As far as the collection classes are concerned, C++ solved with templates and generic programming what Java solved with interfaces and inheritance.

Instances of C++ map template are fully functioning classes that work similarly to Java's `TreeMap`. You can inherit them in the same way that you inherit from classes in Java, and because of multiple inheritance, you are not limited to a single class.

> Also, I don't understand why you would use a typedef.

You use `typedef` to give classes meaningful names. In addition to shortening your typing, it makes your program more readable, and gives you additional flexibility at redefining the class behind the `typedef` later on.

Note: the fact that you *can* inherit from standard containers does not mean that you *should* do it. Read answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6806173/335858) for more information.

Comment: So Map is a class in C++ that's why the author can inherit from it? I think I'll do better just making this a field of the Arguments class in the Java that I'm writing.

Comment: How is a pure virtual abstract class (except with a trivial virtual destructor) inherited from virtually distict from a Java interface?

Comment: @Yakk The first thing that comes to my mind is if you inherit from two such "interfaces", and both of them have a method with the same signature that they did not inherit from a common ancestor, the inheriting class would need to implement both methods separately. In Java, a single implementation would suffice.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `struct A{virtual int f()=0;};struct B{virtual int f()=0;};struct C:virtual A,virtual B{int f(){return 3;};};` impelements both? -- but not if you implement `f` "above" where you mix in one of `A` or `B` , that different in Java?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The link has nothing whatsoever to do with my answer. You did not confuse my answer for a *recommendation* to inherit from standard containers, did you? The fact that you *can* inherit standard containers does not mean that you *should* inherit from them.

Comment: Java doesnt suffer from virtual dtor problem so saying you can inherit like in Java is wrong, ofc IMAO

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I am not aware of C++ "suffering from virtual destructor problem". Of course, like most language features, destructors are open to some misuse, but they do not present a problem in themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are a language construct specific to Java. They do not exist in C++. In C++ you only have classes. You can have abstract classes (classes with unimplemented methods), and eventually you can use them to enunciate interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

`Map` isn't an interface, it's a **template**. Moreover - the author doesn't derive his class from the `map` template as a whole, but he derives from a parametrized template. Without the code of the class, one can only guess **why** he's doing it, and what he wants to achieve.

Note that deriving from STL templates is a bad idea in general (with few exceptional cases) and usually it's much better to make the template a member of your class. Templates don't have `virtual` members and thus - there's no real way to change their behaviour when deriving (and that's the real point of inheritance in many cases).

And a bit about the `typedef`s: when you use a typedef like that, you make your code a bit easier to change in the future. When you (For any reason) decide that you want to implement your own `string` class, you only need to change the first line in this file (from `typedef std::string ArgName;` to `typedef myNewStringClass ArgName;`), instead of changing the code in all the places where `ArgName` occurs.

Comment: I would question your statement "STL templates aren't ment to be base classes in the first place". How do you reconcile that with e.g. a `protected` member in `std::stack`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf maybe that statement was a bit to harsh, and a bit biased. Let me edit that in a way to reflect that.

Comment: I added the code from the class. That was another thing that I found really confusing. It is just the method declarations and no actual implementation. I know that you can do this in C++, but I haven't been able to find the actual implementation in my code yet.

Comment: if the destructor isn't virtual that's a very strong hint that it is not meant to be inherited from

Answer (score 2):

C++ has multiple inheritance, there are no "interfaces". You can certainly inherit from any class. And C++ has templates, something completely absent in Java. Templates allow you to make the compiler write specially tailored functions or classes.