# Inheriting from std::vector, compiler error? (most vexing parse)

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

**For people who see this question:
Take a look at the answer and consider using: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20a%28int%28%29%29)**

Why does the code below give a compiler error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:23:4: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘RangeVec<int>(RangeVec<int>)’
  a.size();
    ^
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Type>
class RangeVec: public std::vector<Type> {
    public:

        RangeVec( const RangeVec & v): std::vector<Type>(v){}
        RangeVec( const RangeVec && v): std::vector<Type>(std::move(v)) {}

        RangeVec( const std::vector<Type> &v)
            : std::vector<Type>(v)
        {
            //std::sort(std::vector<Type>::begin(),std::vector<Type>::end());
        }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    RangeVec<int> b(v);
    RangeVec<int> a(  RangeVec<int>(b) );
    a.size(); // b.size() works ???? why??
}
```

Comment: Most vexing parse, `a` is a function.

Comment: why is it a function?

Comment: @Gabriel, Read about the MVP and you'll see why.

Comment: This is the closest faq entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 RangeVec<int> a(  RangeVec<int>(b) );
```

This is a declaration of a function `a` that returns a `RangeVec<int>` and takes one argument called `b` of type `RangeVec<int>`. This is the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You can fix it with C++11's uniform initialization syntax:

```
 RangeVec<int> a{RangeVec<int>{b}};
```

Or if you don't have a C++11 compiler, just introduce an extra pair of parantheses:

```
 RangeVec<int> a((RangeVec<int>(b)))
```

Note also that deriving from standard containers is [usually a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/150634).

Comment: I though a function declaration looks as follows and not as the above?   ----------------------------------------------

`RangeVec<int> (a)( RangeVec<int> )`

Comment: @Gabriel That's an equivalent declaration (just without the parameter name).

Comment: But how can `RangeVec<int>(b)` be a parameter?
I would aggree that `RangeVec<int> b` is a parameter but with the brackets?? I dont get it

Comment: @Gabriel The same way `int(x);` is a valid declaration of a variable called `x` of type `int`. So is `int(((((((x)))))));`. You can have arbitrary parentheses around the declaration identifier.

Comment: isnt `int(x)` a constructor for an object of type `int` which produces a temporary with no name in the scope

Comment: @Gabriel You're thinking about it when it's an expression (in which case it's the function-like cast notation). Here's it's not an expression, it's a declaration.

Comment: A verygood site is the following to check what the declaration means!  http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+a%28int%28%29%29