# Get the current object being iterated in a list C++

Tags: c++, iterator

So I have a list class `AnimalCollection` which inherits from `list<Animal>`.

Now I am implementing a method called `removeById(int id)` which removes certain item in the collection that matches the specified `id` from the parameter.

My current implementation is below:

```
void AnimalCollection::removeById(int id)
{
    for (auto it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->id == id)
            this->remove((Animal)it);
    }
}
```

Now, on line 6 of my code, it's obvious that it's unwise to convert an iterator to the type that is currently being iterated.

The point is, I want to get the current item being iterated by the iterator `it`.

Anyone who has idea on how to do it?

Comment: can't you dereference `it`? like `this->remove(*it);`

Comment: Are you looking for `*it`?

Comment: OMG, so that's it, hahah. My ignorance. Thanks for the **dereferencing** part. Saved my day.

Comment: Word of advice: don't post code with line numbers. If someone copies your code, first the numbers have to be removed before it can be compiled and executed. I'll edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually hoping for line numbers to be available in code snipping here so it will be easy to specify a part / some parts in your code instead of copying and pasting again. But it will be frustrating for someone to compile that since I didn't give the source for ``AnimalCollection`` and ``Animal`` objects :D Anyway, thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Side note : inheriting from standard containers [has some pitfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers), make sure you know them and avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator returned by [`std::list#begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin) is a [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). As such, it's also an [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) and support the dereference operator (`*it`) to access the underlying object being iterated :

```
this->remove(*it);
```

But note that the call to `remove` will iterate once again over the list to find and remove all elements that equals to `*it`.

Alternatively, you could use [`std::list#erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) to directly remove the iterator (and only the element referenced by it) from the list and avoid a possible useless iteration :

```
for (auto it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ) {
    if (it->id == id) {
        it = this->erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

*Note that if you call `erase(it)`, your iterator `it` will be invalidated, thus in order to continue to iterate the list, we use the iterator returned by `erase` wich point to the element following the last removed element, possibly `end()`*

Comment: Glady appreciated for pointing 2 concepts as solutions for my question. Thanks mate (bow)

Comment: Caution : you should not increment `it` at the end of an iteration if you used `it = erase(it);`. Otherwise, erasing the last element will increment `it` past `end()`.

Comment: Caution returns : your fix will shove `it` before `begin()` if you `erase()` the first element ;)

Comment: I chose this as **The Best Answer** since he elaborated perfectly and completely, not only the solutions, but also possible countermeasure for another incoming problem.

Everyone else, thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Caution is satisfied and has left an upvote for your time. Enjoy your coffee :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is remove the element referred by `it` then [`erase(it)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) is what you need.