# resizing a vector of vectors causes a seg fault

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class MyVect:private std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >
{
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > super;

public:
///When this is commented out -- No Seg Fault//////////////
    std::vector<std::string>& operator[](int plt)
    {
        return static_cast<super>(*this)[(int)plt];
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    MyVect()
    {
        this->resize(4); // this works fine
        for (int i = 0; i<4;i++)
        {
            (*this)[i].resize(3); // I think this doesn't 
        }
        (*this)[0][0] = "hello";
    }
};
```

The above code, causes a seg fault and I can't figure out what is wrong?

```
*** glibc detected *** invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x09267040
```

Comment: @BryanChen Please don't mislead. There is no such rule.

Comment: [Inherit from `std::vector` is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers/7110262#7110262).

Comment: @BryanChen Much of the arguments in there don't apply to private inheritance.

Comment: @BryanChen Well the most critical reason in that link you mentioned is that the destructor of std::vector is not virtual. However, since I know I will never use an std::vector pointer to reference my object, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static_cast<super>(*this)` creates a temporary and slices `*this`.

You want `static_cast<super&>(*this)`.

Comment: @Kam Again always be careful with casting... C++ style casting can be just as dangerous as C style.