# Replace existing data type with custom one?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I have a class `_vector` which I want to replace by `std::vector` in all instances of the code without manually changing the literal text of it. In a way, i want to replace the functionality of `std::vector` with a custom one which is a derived class of it.

My custom class is a one template parameter class which inherits from `std::vector<T>` where I implemented additional `operator[]` functionality. I want to replace all the `std::vector`s in the code by the custom one.

I tried to do

```
template <class T>
using vector = _vector<T>;
```

But when creating a `std::vector` it says that the call is ambiguous, which makes sense.

I also tried to use `typedef` in all posible combinations involving templates, with no avail, like so

```
template <class T>
typedef _vector<T> vector<T>;
```

I also tried to define `std::vector` as `_vector`, using

```
#define vector _vector
```

But it changes all the implementations of `std::vector` in `_vector`, even if I put this line after the class definition, as it is a preprocessor directive and is ran before compiling it.

I don't what more to do, and if someone has an answer, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: You probably have `using namespace std;` at global scope. Remove it and redeclare your vector in your own namespace so names won't collide. Also identifies at global namespace beginning with underscore are reserved.

Comment: @VTT What does it affect?

Comment: Please stop trying to do this.  Do not do this.  Do not go down the path of making your code "magically" use some other type when `std::vector` is plainly written.  Future maintainers are going to hate you--and you might be one of them.  Just change your code to use "myvector" or whatever.  Do not call it `_vector` because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: Well, I used _vector to be easier to read, in the code itself it has a valid name, and i dont collaborate with anyone, so thats not the problem.

Comment: Deriving from `std::vector` is a terrible idea to begin with.

Comment: @Christian why?

Comment: @user7908643: Generally, deriving from *anything* which isn't explicitly designed to be derived from is a terrible idea, in every programming language. There are countless in-depth explanations for this on Stack Overflow, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers/