# (Re)named std::pair members breaks initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, subclassing, std-pair

Had following type:

```
typedef pair<double, double> MinMax; ///< first - Min, second - Max
```

and initialization with it worked fine:

```
const MinMax mInMinMax[FunctionCount] = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}};
```

However if I subclass pair for convenience:

```
///< first - Min, second - Max
struct MinMax : public pair<double, double>
{
    double& Min() { return first; }
    double Min() const { return first; }
    double& Max() { return second; }
    double Max() const { return second; }
};
```

Compilation fails with error:

> `error: could not convert ‘{-1, 1}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer
>   list>’ to ‘const MinMax’ 
>   const MinMax mInMinMax[FunctionCount] = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}};`

Is it possible to subclass `pair<double, double>` correctly?

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to subclass STL containers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers/7110262#7110262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of the base class is not "inherited" automatically.
Your `Min`/`Max` functions have nothing to do with this problem:

```
struct MinMax : public pair<double, double>
{
   using pair<double, double>::pair;
   ...
};
```