# std::array derived class aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, aggregate-initialization

I am making a small helper class that derives from `std::array`. The constructor does not inherit, obviously, and it is that which is responsible for brace-initialization; for example:

```
template<typename T, size_t size>
struct foo : std::array<T,size>
{
     foo(int a, int b)
     : std::array<T,size>{a,b}
     {
          //nothing goes here since constructor is just a dummy that 
          //forwards all arguments to std::array constructor
     }
}

int main()
{
     foo<int,2> myobj = {1,2}; //brace initialization calls custom constructor with inner elements as arguments
}
```

The amount of arguments has to match exactly, so I am leaning towards using something like a variadic function argument in the constructor (since I am not only going to be using 2 elements in the array every single time). Using this, how would I forward the variadic argument pack to the `std::array` constructor? I am open to other methods of brace initialization that allow forwarding to the `std::array` constructor.

Note: `std::initializer_list` requires runtime initialization, and i am looking for a compile time/constexpr compatible method. Thank you.

Comment: I question the premise of deriving from `std::array`. While this has nothing to do with the question, you should know that inheriting from `std` containers is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers/7110262).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a perfect-forwarding constructor:

```
template<class... U>
foo(U&&... u)
    : std::array<T, size>{std::forward<U>(u)...}
{}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I'd also like to add (for the future readers of this question), that this causes a compilation error for GCC 5.1 (the version I'm using), but works perfectly in GCC 6.0 and above.

Comment: I think this constructor should also be marked `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that inheriting from a standard container is a good idea.

Anyway...

You can use variadic templates, perfect forwarding and also SFINAE to impose that the number of arguments is exactly `size`.

You can also make `constexpr` the `foo` constructor so you can make `constexpr foo` objects.

By example

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
struct foo : public std::array<T, S>
 {
   template <typename ... As,
             typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(As) == S>::type * = nullptr>
   constexpr foo (As && ... as)
      : std::array<T, S>{ { std::forward<As>(as)... } }
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   //constexpr foo<int, 2u> myobj1 = {1}; // compilation error
   constexpr foo<int, 2u> myobj2 = {1, 2}; // compile
   //constexpr foo<int, 2u> myobj3 = {1, 2, 3}; // compilation error
 }
```