# What is std::map<K,V>::map; and how do you know what namespace to use when implementing/using stl containers and functions?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, namespaces, overloading

I am trying to write a class that inherits the std::map but I also want to overload one specific function while keeping the remaining inherited functions available for use. After reading a bit about that it seems you have to use the namespace of map to be able to use it's functions. However I had to use `using std::map<K,V>::map;` for it to be working. My question is what is the last `::map`? Is it the name of the namespace of map? But if we take cout for example you simply needed `using cout;`. Also how does one know the name of the namespaces i stl?

The code looks something like this:

```
#include <map>

template<typename K,typename V>
class my_map : public std::map<K,V>
{   
private:
    /* data */ 
public:
    using std::map<K,V>::map;
};
```

Comment: `using Base::Base;` is called [inheriting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors).

Comment: Beware that [publicly inheriting from standard types can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers). It *can* work but you have to be careful because they weren't designed to be derived from.

Comment: Good tip, I will watch out for that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using std::map<K,V>::map;
```

You need to use it if u want to use the base ctors outside the class (to inherit the constructors).

And this `std::map<K,V>::map` is the constructor and qualified by the class name.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct terminology is. Because `using T::T;` works even if `T` doesn't have a default constructor. So it can't be naming or referring to a constructor. It is just a special case for a `using` declaration, as far as I know.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux agreed.

Comment: [The standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#1) uses "names a constructor" so I suppose that is allowed after all. I guess you can put it back the way it was.

Comment: Aha, so it's the constructor! I got it. Would this inherit all the member functions in map as well? Or how would I otherwise gain access to its member functions?

Comment: @Sekai Since your inheritance is `public` all the `public` members of the base class are already inherited.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yea it most likely is an exception I guess.

Comment: @Sekai the ctors are exception. you can access the rest functions as the following.     `my_map<int, int> my_map_obj;
    my_map_obj.insert({2,2});`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh I understand. Thanks a bunch for explaining! :D