# How can I hash a type using the std::hash of its base class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, stdhash

I have a class template `C<B>` which inherits from `std::string`, and I want to make it hashable like a normal `std::string`. I have written the following code, and it compiles.

I wonder if it is the correct implementation. Since a cast from derived class to base class may truncate memory, I wonder if it will cost too much?

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

template <bool B>
struct C : std::string
{
    C(std::string s) : std::string(s) {}
};

namespace std {

    template <bool B>
    struct hash<C<B>>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const C<B> &k) const {
            return std::hash<std::string>()(static_cast<std::string>(k));
        }
    };

} // namespace std

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<C<false>> s;
    std::string c = C<false>("a");
    s.insert(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: it's usually not recommended to inherit std types like `std::string`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers.

Comment: `C` has no members, there is nothing to be truncated.

Comment: The constructor should be rewritten to `C(std::string s) : std::string(std::move(s)) {}` to avoid an extra memory allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the implementation will work, but `static_cast<std::string>(k)` is not needed - and will create a temporary `std::string` which you probably would like to avoid.

If you instead make it `static_cast<const std::string&>(k)`, it will not create a temporary `std::string`. Same thing if you simply do:

```cpp
std::size_t operator()(const C<B>& k) const {
    return std::hash<std::string>()(k);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, it works. However, in the mean time I came up with another idea with `string_view`, it also compiles, I wonder if it is also a good way to solve this?

Comment: @calvin You're welcome! Using a `std::string_view` inside the `std::hash<class_derived_from_string>::operator()` will have no benefit as I can see it. It just creates a `string_view` and hashes that instead of the string - but the algorithm is most likely the same. It is in all implementations I've looked at.