# Implement Non Copyable Non Moveable wrapper for map/vector etc

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stl, c++14

I want to write a wrapper over the STL containers like map, vector, unordered map etc. that do not have copy or move constructors. There are a few approaches that I can think of, but none are nice:

**Approach 1:** Use templates:

```
// Define a template NoCopyMove which can be instantiated with STL container types.
template <typename V>
struct NoCopyMove {
 public:
  using value_type = V;
  value_type& get() { return val_; }

  template <typename... Args>
  NoCopyMove(Args&&... args): val_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

 private:
  NoCopyMove(const NoCopyMove&) = delete;
  NoCopyMove(NoCopyMove&&) = delete;
  value_type val_;
};
```

The above can be instantiated with any STL container and then the container can be accessed using the `get()` function

**Approach 2:** Use Public Inheritance:

```
template <typename Key,
          typename T,
          typename Hash = std::hash<Key>,
          typename KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
class unordered_map_ncm
    : public std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator> {
  // Inherit constructors.
  using std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator>::unordered_map;

 private:
  unordered_map_ncm(const unordered_map_ncm&) = delete;
  unordered_map_ncm(unordered_map_ncm&&) = delete;
};
```

The above is susceptible to pointer slicing because STL containers do not have virtual constructors and has to be done for each STL type. The upside is that we get to use STL-like functions without the `.get()` call in the template-based approach.

**Approach 2':** The above can be generalized further so that instead of a map, any STL type can be used as follows:

```
template <template <typename...> class T, typename... Us>
class NoCopyMove : public T<Us...> {
public:
    using T<Us...>::T;

private:
    NoCopyMove(const NoCopyMove&) = delete;
    NoCopyMove(NoCopyMove&&) = delete;
};

template<typename Key,
          typename T,
          typename Hash = std::hash<Key>,
          typename KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
using unordered_map_ncm = NoCopyMove<std::unordered_map, Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator>;
```

Even after this improvement, we have the drawback of pointer slicing.

I cannot think of anything which gives a friendly usage without the pointer slicing drawback. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Is it just curiosity?

Comment: What's the problem with the pointer slicing? A "sliced" pointer is essentially the same as `&o.get()`, and that seems desirable (it behaves no differently to a container that wasn't inside a `NoCopyMove`)

Comment: Approach 2'' `template <class T> class NoCopyMove : T {/**/}; template </**/>using unordered_map_ncm = NoCopyMove<std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator>>;` (which handle `std::array`:) ).

Comment: @273K I have stated it towards the end:
`I cannot think of anything which gives a friendly usage without the pointer slicing drawback.`

I do not consider calling `.get` everytime I have to access map/vector a friendly usage. I do not want pointer slicing either.

Comment: Not related to the downvote, unless someone was really grumpy today, but the term STL refers to the Standard Template Library, a library that was a huge influence on parts of the C++ Standard Library (and often provided large portions of the initial implementations of the influenced parts) when C++ was standardized back in 1998. STL and the C++ Standard Library are distinct libraries and, to prevent confusion in the cases where the differences really matter, should not be used interchangeably.

Comment: just a tip, when you delete constructors, make them public for better compilation errors

Comment: Why is the "pointer slicing" ever an issue ? You just don't have to try to do polymorphism with your container. After all, if someone tries to use a container polymorphically, this one is mistaken. Each container has its own purpose and using them interchangeably (e.g. `std::vector` and `std::list`) does not make sense at all (serves you right Java :p ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to privately inherit from the container - than to have it as private member - because we can use `use Base::xxxx;` to get types and methods from it.

And of course - delete copy constructor and assign operator (move will be deleted too that way).

If we close our eyes on that we cannot prevent from copying element one by one `NoCopy<std::vector<int>> v; std::vector<int> a(v.begin(), a.end());` - then this should work:

1. Have one class, the main class of this module, with common set of types and methods:

```
namespace detail {
template <typename Base>
struct ContainerSpecific : Base {
    using Base::Base;
};
}

template <typename Container>
struct ContainerNotCopyable : private detail::ContainerSpecific<Container>
// note: this is private      ^^^^^^^  inheritance: 
{
    using Base = detail::ContainerSpecific<Container>;
    using Base::Base;

    ContainerNotCopyable(const ContainerNotCopyable&) = delete;
    ContainerNotCopyable& operator=(const ContainerNotCopyable&) = delete;

    // common stl containers types
    using Container::size_type;
    using Container::value_type;
    using Container::iterator;
    using Container::const_iterator;
    using Container::reverse_iterator;
    using Container::const_reverse_iterator;

    // common stl containers methods
    using Container::size;
    using Container::empty;
    using Container::begin;
    using Container::rbegin;
    using Container::cbegin;
    using Container::end;
    using Container::cend;
    using Container::rend;
};
```

2. Then for each container that is needed, add specific operations and types specific to it:

```
namespace detail {
template <typename ...T>
struct ContainerSpecific<std::vector<T...>> : std::vector<T...> {
    using Base = std::vector<T...>;
    using Base::Base;

    using Base::operator[];
    using Base::at;
    using Base::erase;
    using Base::clear;
};
}

template <typename T, typename A=std::allocator<T>>
using VectorNotCopyable = ContainerNotCopyable<std::vector<T,A>>;

namespace detail {
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ContainerSpecific<std::array<T, N>> : std::array<T, N> {
    using Base = std::array<T, N>;
    using Base::Base;

    using Base::operator[];
    using Base::at;
};
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using ArrayNotCopyable = ContainerNotCopyable<std::array<T,N>>;

namespace detail {
template <typename ...T>
struct ContainerSpecific<std::map<T...>> : std::map<T...> {
    using Base = std::map<T...>;
    using Base::Base;
    using Base::mapped_type;
    using Base::key_type;

    using Base::find;


    using Base::emplace;
    using Base::insert;
    using Base::insert_or_assign;
    using Base::try_emplace;
};
}
template <typename K, typename V, typename C=std::less<K>, typename A=std::allocator<std::pair<const K, V>>>
using MapNotCopyable = ContainerNotCopyable<std::map<K,V,C,A>>;
```

Now, we can check it works as expected:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_no_copy_move =
        !std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>
     && !std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>
     && !std::is_move_constructible_v<T>
     && !std::is_move_assignable_v<T>;

static_assert(has_no_copy_move<VectorNotCopyable<int>>);
static_assert(has_no_copy_move<ArrayNotCopyable<int, 7>>);
static_assert(has_no_copy_move<MapNotCopyable<int, int>>);
```

Comment: Inheriting from standard library types is generally a bad idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110262/5494370

Comment: This is private inheritance - so any claim about encapsulation or wrong usage of  IS-A relationship do not apply. You cannot have object slicing too with private inheritance, unless you do it in own methods or in some friend functions/methods. All these concerns about inheritance are  for public inheritance (and maybe protected one within family).

Comment: If you are well-aware of what you can and cannot do, what doors will be open and what doors will be closed, there is no issue inheriting from standard library types. All those "inheritance-is-evil" war is more moralization than real advices. If the relation "is a" is fulfilled, then inheritance is good to go. No virtual destructor ? Who cares ? Inheritance do not mean polymorphism (people always make the confusion hence why those wrong advices come up).

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare forwarding methods for all the methods you want to use on the class, e.g.:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename V>
struct NoCopyMove {
 public:
  using value_type = V;
  value_type& get() { return val_; }

  template <typename... Args>
  NoCopyMove(Args&&... args): val_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  auto begin()
  {
    return val_.begin();
  }

  auto begin() const
  {
    return val_.begin();
  }

  auto end()
  {
    return val_.end();
  }

  auto end() const
  {
    return val_.end();
  }

  template <typename Value>
  void push_back(Value && v)
    requires requires (Value && v) { value_type{}.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v)); }
  {
    val_.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v));
  }

  template <typename ... Params>
  void insert(Params && ...v)
    requires requires (Params && ...v) { value_type{}.insert(std::forward<Params>(v)...); }
  {
    val_.insert(std::forward<Params>(v)...);
  }

 private:
  NoCopyMove(const NoCopyMove&) = delete;
  NoCopyMove(NoCopyMove&&) = delete;
  value_type val_;
};

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    NoCopyMove<std::vector<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(10);
    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    NoCopyMove<std::map<int, int>> map;
    map.insert(map.end(), std::pair{1, 1});
}
```

As long as you don't try and call an invalid method it'll compile even when the method doesn't exist in `value_type`. e.g.:

```
NoCopyMove<std::map<int, int>> map;
```

compiles but:

```
map.push_back(std::pair{1, 1});
```

will produce an error:

```
<source>:36:10: error: no member named 'push_back' in 'std::map<int, int>'
   36 |     val_.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v));
      |     ~~~~ ^
<source>:58:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'NoCopyMove<std::map<int, int>>::push_back<std::pair<int, int>>' requested here
   58 |     map.push_back(std::pair{1, 1});
      |         ^
```

If you can use c++20 you can make the errors a little more direct with concepts:

```
  template <typename Value>
  void push_back(Value && v)
    requires requires (Value && v) { value_type{}.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v)); }
  {
    val_.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v));
  }
```

`map.push_back` will now give:

```
<source>:58:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
   58 |     map.push_back(std::pair{1, 1});
      |     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:33:8: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with Value = std::pair<int, int>]
   33 |   void push_back(Value && v)
      |        ^
<source>:34:51: note: because 'value_type{}.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v))' would be invalid: no member named 'push_back' in 'std::map<int, int>'
   34 |     requires requires (Value && v) { value_type{}.push_back(std::forward<Value>(v)); }
      |                                                   ^
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qE51sYEbE

Comment: Evaluated this approach as well. But this will add a lot of boilerplate if it has to be done across all STL containers.

Comment: You have only one big class with all APIs, not several class to write.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I understood that part.

Comment: Well, it is easy to work around the restriction - `NoCopyMove<std::map<int, int>> mapNotCopyable;   std::map<int, int> foo(mapNotCopyable.begin(), mapNotCopyable.end());`.

Comment: @Jarod42 We shouldn't have one big class for all containers. It needs to be specialized for containers - otherwise - what means clear() for std::array?

Comment: @PiotrNycz the wrapper will reject attempts to use methods which don't exist on the wrapped class

Comment: @AlanBirtles what about types - like key_type or mapped_type in std::map ? And - SFINAE or concepts can detect, for example: `clear()` exist in a type - but it shall not be detected...

Comment: @PiotrNycz concepts already work: https://godbolt.org/z/4rsMorET9, they check that the call will compile, the same for SFINAE. I'm sure there would be a way to get typedefs too if you really needed them (the OP didn't ask for them)

Comment: Yes - we can do some mixin class that introduces mapped_type/key_type...