# C++ Vector Front

Tags: c++, vector, element, deque

I'm having trouble with the getFirst() functions , they're supposed to return the first element of the deque / vector but instead they return fixed values like 45 or 69!

For example: I Add(0xFB) ... then try to printf("%d",p_MsgQueue->getFirst())
Output: 69 ????

MessageQueue.h

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 - 2012 Project Avalance
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA
 */

#ifndef MESSAGEQUEUE_H
#define MESSAGEQUEUE_H

#define MQ_USE_DEQUE

#ifdef MQ_USE_VECTOR
#include <vector>
/* THIS VECTOR WILL BE USED BY MESSAGE_QUEUE TO STORE THE-TO BE PROCCESSED MESSAGES (SLASH) SIGNALS.*/
typedef std::vector<int> MESSAGE_LIST; // SHARED OBJECT .. MUST LOCK!

/* THIS CLASS WILL HANDLE THE MESSAGE LIST.*/
class MESSAGE_QUEUE {
public:
    MESSAGE_LIST * m_pList; // Pointer to our list, it's better to leave MESSAGE_LIST outside this class.
    MESSAGE_QUEUE(MESSAGE_LIST* pList){ m_pList = pList; } // POINTER TO OUR LIST HANDLER = POINTER TO THE LIST CREATED BY THE CALLING SCOPE MESSAGE_QUEUE (&AddressOfList)
    ~MESSAGE_QUEUE(){ } // Destructor , this will destroy m_pList when the class gets out of scope (todo)
    /* This class will be shared between threads that means any attempt to access it MUST be inside a critical section. */
    void Add( int messageCode ){ if(m_pList && messageCode!=0xFF)m_pList->push_back(messageCode);  } // Adding a message; Added check if input is 0xFF.
    int getLast( ){ if(m_pList){ return m_pList->back(); } return -1; } // MUST BE IN THE CODE : if(m_pList->size() == 0){ add(0xFF); } -- 0xFF CODE IS RESERVED! DO - NOT - USE
    void removeLast( ){ if(m_pList && m_pList->size() > 0){ m_pList->erase(m_pList->end()-1,m_pList->end()); } } // Deleting the last message , idk about iters+1 efficiency, there might be other ways to do it like advance(const_iterator,int)
    void removeFirst( ){ if(m_pList && m_pList->size() > 0){ m_pList->erase(m_pList->begin()); } }
    int getFirst( ){ if(m_pList){ return m_pList->front(); } return -1; }
};
#endif

#ifdef MQ_USE_DEQUE
#include <deque>
/* THIS VECTOR WILL BE USED BY MESSAGE_QUEUE TO STORE THE-TO BE PROCCESSED MESSAGES (SLASH) SIGNALS.*/
typedef std::deque<int> MESSAGE_LIST; // SHARED OBJECT .. MUST LOCK!

/* THIS CLASS WILL HANDLE THE MESSAGE LIST.*/
class MESSAGE_QUEUE {
public:
    MESSAGE_LIST * m_pList; // Pointer to our list, it's better to leave MESSAGE_LIST outside this class.
    MESSAGE_QUEUE(MESSAGE_LIST* pList){ m_pList = pList; } // POINTER TO OUR LIST HANDLER = POINTER TO THE LIST CREATED BY THE CALLING SCOPE MESSAGE_QUEUE (&AddressOfList)
    ~MESSAGE_QUEUE(){ } // Destructor , this will destroy m_pList when the class gets out of scope (todo)
    /* This class will be shared between threads that means any attempt to access it MUST be inside a critical section. */
    void Add( int messageCode ){ if(m_pList && messageCode!=0xFF)m_pList->push_back(messageCode);  } // Adding a message; Added check if input is 0xFF.
    int getLast( ){ if(m_pList){ return m_pList->back(); } return -1;} // MUST BE IN THE CODE : if(m_pList->size() == 0){ add(0xFF); } -- 0xFF CODE IS RESERVED! DO - NOT - USE
    void removeLast( ){ if(m_pList && m_pList->size() > 0){ m_pList->erase(m_pList->end()-1,m_pList->end()); } } // Deleting the last message , idk about iters+1 efficiency, there might be other ways to do it like advance(const_iterator,int)
    void removeFirst( ){ if(m_pList && m_pList->size() > 0){ m_pList->erase(m_pList->begin()); } }
    int getFirst( ){ if(m_pList){ return m_pList->front(); } return -1;}
};
#endif

#endif
```

Somewhere in Command.h

```
            ArgParser arg;
            int value = arg.GetHexArgs(_input,strlen("message -add 0x"));
            if(value == -1)CLog->out("\n Bad Arguement!");
            if(value != -1)CLog->out("\n 0x%X",value);
            LockSection Lc(Cs,errHandler);
            msgQueue->Add(value);
            printf(" %d ",msgQueue->getFirst());
            Lc.ForceCSectionLeave();
```

Main.cpp

```
LockSection lc(&crt,&err);
CLog->out(" [ Adding message = 0x45 ] Action : None \n");
g_msgQueue.Add(0x45);
CLog->out(" [ Adding message = 0xFD ] Action : Stalling Backgrounder Thread...\n");
g_msgQueue.Add(0xFD);
lc.ForceCSectionLeave();

/* Initialize Manager/Threads */
Backgrounder backgrounder;
if(backgrounder.Begin(&g_msgQueue,&crt,&err) == -1){ CLog->out(" - Initializing Backgrounder Sevice (backgrounder)  ... Failed!\n [Warning]! An error occured while initializing Backgrounder Sevice (backgrounder)."); }

CommandManager Cmd_Mgr;
if(Cmd_Mgr.Begin(&g_msgQueue,&crt,&err) == -1){ CLog->out(" - Initializing Command Manager Service (Cmd_Mgr)  ... Failed!\n [Warning]! An error occured while initializing Command Manager Service (Cmd_Mgr)."); }

while(g_msgQueue.getLast() != 0xFF){ 
    if(g_msgQueue.getLast() == 0xFE){
        CLog->out("\n == WARNING == SERVICE RESTART MESSAGE WAS RECIEVED .... REBOOTING ALL SECONDARY THREADS! "); // Todo, _endthread // and nicely reboot

    }
}
return 0;
```

It turns out I was adding values in a different file.
Notice the:

```
LockSection lc(&crt,&err);
CLog->out(" [ Adding message = 0x45 ] Action : None \n");
g_msgQueue.Add(0x45);
CLog->out(" [ Adding message = 0xFD ] Action : Stalling Backgrounder Thread...\n");
g_msgQueue.Add(0xFD);
lc.ForceCSectionLeave();
```

Comment: What's with the ALL CAPS code? ALL_CAPS in C++ usually indicate macros. And why is *every single function* written on a single line? It's really hard to read the code because of that.

Comment: `YOU FORGOT TO TURN CAPS LOCK ON; SOME OF THE COMMENTS ARE IN LOWERCASE.`

Comment: Why are you inheriting from std::vector? You're not supposed to do that!

Comment: Thats my coding style. It's much easier for me to read when everything is in 1 line ._.

Comment: @Iarsmans i /lol'ed at that ^^!

Comment: @NT_SYSTEM: No offense. Your coding style seems to me a paragraph from a novel.

Comment: @NT_SYSTEM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector/4353333#4353333

Comment: @NT_SYSTEM STD's container classes were not designed for such things. For one, none (specifically the destructor) of its methods are virtual.

Comment: @Pubby8: you must mean `std`, did you catch the ALL CAPS virus?

Comment: @LARSMAN RESISTANCE IS FUTILE.

Comment: Well, I don't know why i inherited it in the first place, I must have had something else in my mind at that time. Even without it, the problem is still there. return vec->front doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you guys voting down my question?

Comment: @NT_SYSTEM are you sure you are passing a valid vector into the constructor? Are you sure that the vector stays valid as long as MESSAGE_QUEUE?

Comment: @Pubby8 Yes , 100% sure. It works fine if i use ->Add(5) and ->GetLast() on the other hand ->GetFirst() doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the function Add() will always print out the first element you added: if you ad 69, 45, 89, 34 it will always print 69 that is the first added element
- You don't need to derive from MESSAGE_LIST (vector or queue), you are just using them in the m_pList member
- if m_pList is null your program will crash because you are not returning any value when you are supposed to

Comment: 1) Printf was just to test if it returns the first element ... because  i added only 1 element. Removed now, 'cause it was there just to debug

Comment: 2) Inheriting MESSAGE_LIST was fixed long ago xP.

Comment: 3) Three was fixed too, but the main problem is still there. GetFirst doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the pointer to the vector you pass in the constructor of MESSAGE_QUEUE is valid and that the vector is initially empty?

Comment: If it was empty .. GetLast() would not return a value, but it does.

Comment: @NT_SYSTEM What vector are you passing into the constructor?

Comment: Turns out i was adding values in main.cpp ... notice the .Add(0x45) .Add(0xFD)