# Delegate/forward function to member (composition)

Tags: c++, delegates, wrapper, forwarding

Suppose I have the class

```
template<class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    Vector() = default;

    inline size_t size() const { return _vector.size(); }

  private :
    std::vector<T> _vector;
};
```

Is there any way to delegate functions (or operators) to `_vector`, **at compile time, without overhead** ?

I can of course (and it's what I'm doing) forward everything by declaring every functions I need, and just call the appropriate function to the member, as I did with `size()`.

[This article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1363.htm) propose exactly what I would need. For example using this :

```
template<class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    Vector() = default;

  private :
    std::vector<T> _vector;

  public:
    using _vector {
      size_t size() const;
      void push_back(const T&);
    }
};
```

The compiler would then generate the appropriate code. But I didn't find anything like this, is it possible ?

Comment: I think I'm gonna suffer for mentioning it, but it's possible with private inheritance & using...

Comment: Your inlined function likely *will* forward at compile time without any overhead. The proposed shorthand for forwarding didn't make it into the standard, so you will have to do it by hand.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, I just wanted a lazy way to do it without writing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way**: You can inherit `std::vector<T>` publicly to make such delegation possible:

```
template<class T>
class Vector : public std::vector<T>
...
```

Whether to inherit `std::vector` or not is little [debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector), but then it's your code.

<strike>**Second way**: If you are particular about the composition then make `Vector<T>` objects behave as smart pointers:</strike>

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
  std::vector<T> _vector;    
public:
  std::vector<T>* operator -> () { return &_vector; }
};
Vector<int> vi;
vi->size(); // instead of vi.size()
```

**Third way**: Overload `operator ()` for syntactic sugar:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
  std::vector<T> _vector;
public:
  std::vector<T>& operator ()() { return _vector; }
  const std::vector<T>& operator ()() const { return _vector; }
};
Vector<int> vi;
vi().size(); // instead of vi.size()
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid inheritance. I like other solutions. What would be the syntax to call `operator[]` with the second one ? Any drawbacks for those solutions ?

Comment: @ThePluc, 2nd solution is not that much effective alone. You may have to overload `operator *()` also to make it complete. BTW, why do you want to avoid inheritance ?

Comment: Because I used this simple example to explain what I wanted, but the real class would be a true composition with different members, also containers are not designed to be inherited (I saw your link :p). I'll use the  `operator()` after checking if that's ok for me, otherwise I'll just declare by hand. I think the syntax for the second solution might be misleading, especially if working with a pointer.

Comment: Just to say I accepted this as the answer since it provides an alternative with a simple syntax. The real answer is that it's not possible at the moment though :)