# c++ wrapping types for semantic

Tags: c++

It has been a long time since my last use of c++, coming back from java and python, I have a question about good practices on c++:

I wanted to keep a semantic code about some really simple objects, let's say we have objects Tag and File, which both only are std::string and a class TagManager which contains several functions using Tags and Files.

My question is, is it better to create a custom type representing these trivial objects or to use them directly for what they are?

To be more specific I have could have one of those definitions for a function:

```
TagIterable myFunction(Tag tag, File file);
std::vector<Tag> myFunction(Tag tag, File file);
std::vector<std::string> myFunction(std::string tag, std::string file);
```

I prefer the first solution because I like to keep a semantic code, on the other hand doing it requires the user to check what these types are, so it reduce the simplicity of use.

I also read on another question ([Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector)) 'Do not produce new entities just to make something to look better.'

So what do you do in such situation; what does the C++ philosophy recommend to do?

Comment: File stands for an actual file? or does it mean it's a filename? Then it'd be a better idea to call it filename as it could mislead other people using your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `typedef`s in such cases:

- Even though `typedef`s don't introduce new types or nasty derivatives of `std::vector<>` themselves, the aliases may still be possibly annoying indirections for those using your code.
- On the other hand, they could be exposed and documented well (provide an example), so that everybody uses them from start.
- They help to avoid build breakers, in case the type needs to be changed (provided, that special `std::string` features aren't used or are provided in the replacement, in your specific case).
- So, if required, a `typedef` could later be changed to alias a new class with extra properties and functions, or just for type safety.
- They allow easy tracking of usage locations, as well as refactoring in most IDEs.

```
namespace mylib
{
    typedef std::string Tag; //perhaps 'TagType' or 'tag_type', to follow the naming
                             //conventions of the standard library, e.g.
                             //std::vector::value_type
    typedef std::string File;//Same as above, 'FileName' might be more appropriate

    typedef std::vector<Tag> TagIterable;
                             //Could be named 'TagContainer',
                             //`TagVector` or `TagSet` when using std::set,
                             //to match the terminology of C++

    TagIterable myFunction(const Tag& tag,const File& file);
                             //One may use references to const here,
                             //to explicitly avoid unnecessary copies

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Its called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (also known as data hiding). If encapuslating the concept of a `File` and a `Tag` adds value, then go ahead and do it, otherwise you're just adding complexity. It could be that later you decide to use `std::wstring` instead of a simple `std::string` internally in the classes, which you could easily change if you create the `Tag` and `File` classes, and the users of the classes most likely wont be impacted.

As for inheriting from std::vector, that is indeed something you should avoid. But remember: inheriting and encapsulation are 2 completely different concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Being the type freak that I am, I always include new types.

Writing the wrapper code is easy enough:

```
class Tag {
public:
    Tag() {}
    explicit Tag(std::string const& v): _value(v) {}
    std::string const& get() const { return _value; }
private:
    std::string _value;
}; // class Tag
```

And that's it!

`typedef` are nice and all, but it's too easy to mix them up and use operations that do not make sense: what does `Tag::substr` means ?

Answer (score 1):

i'd preferr to use what c++ provides you with unless it's *really* necessary to make an alias. Why don't just use self-speaking identifyers? My Solution would look like:

```
std::vector<std::string> getTagsFromFile(std::string tag, std::string fileName);
```

Comment: In general simpler is always better. Something else to consider is that encapsulating it will make it future-proof to implementation changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some valid use cases for wrapping (simple) types:

- Makeing types distinct. For example an identifier which will be unique for some context.
- Give a type a unit (US gallon 3.79 vs. imperial gallon 4.546) - for example boost::unit.
  The unit is actually an additional information.
- ...

For each wrapping you would create a distinct class (template) to ensure type safety.
A simple typedef would not encapsulate anything, but clarify usage, only.