# C++ Inherit from std::vector to implement container type?

Tags: oop, inheritance, c++11, stl, polymorphism

What is the correct method of inheriting a standard library class to implement a new container type?

I assume that inheriting from std::vector is not the exact correct method, although I do not know whether it would actually work or not.

I assume std::vector inherits from another class and that I should inherit that class in order to implement a new type of container, is this correct, and if so what should be inherited?

Is there anything else I need to know, for example, what modifications I may need to make to the std::iterator group of objects?

Comment: What container type are you trying to implement? It is very likely you don't need to do so, and would be better off using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: There's also a lot of good discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt?lq=1) (it's about C#, but the topics are pretty widely applicable)

Answer (score 0):

### Class which inherits from vector

**Matrix.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Matrix: public std::vector<T>
{
public:
   using std::vector<T>::vector;

private:
};
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
int main()
{
   Matrix<int> dani;
   dani.push_back(2);
   dani.push_back(3);

   for(const auto& it: dani)
      std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

### Class which contains a vector

You can overload operators, if you like this method you can see here the complete example class with

- **templates**
- **matrix opperations**
- **operators overloading**

in github: [here](https://github.com/dani2442/Vector/blob/master/Vector/Vector.h)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int);
    Vector(int, int);

    ~Vector();

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> v;

    bool Check_Size() ;
    template<typename T1> bool Check_Size(std::vector<T1>&) ;
    template<typename T1> bool Check_Size_Fast(std::vector<T1>&);

    void Print();

    void Transponse();

    void Inverse();
    void Inverse2();
    void Inverse3();


    template<class T,class Q>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator* (const Q , Vector<T> );
    ...

};
```