# Class inherited from a vector of itself

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdvector

It is possible in C++ to declare such class:

```
class A : public std::vector<A>
{
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
}
```

Ok, it is bad to inherit from STL containers, it is bad to hide non-virtual destructor.

But is there any purpose of classes like this? What it can be used for?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: @inetknght, in order to get the benefit of CRTP, the base needs to be aware of it. `std::vector<>` is certainly not.

Comment: Sure, absolutely. But OP asked *"is there any purpose of classes like this?"* which I interpreted to mean *"is there any purpose of a curiously recurring template pattern?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since destructor of `std::vector<>` is non-virtual, there is no point in making destructor of derived class virtual - your class will not behave polymorphically when base is used.

However, there might be some benefit in using non-polymorphic inheritance, for instance, by overriding some `vector` functions.

Comment: Sorry, I removed `virtual`.

Comment: But what the reason to declare `A` as inherited from vector of `A`? What is the profit? Just for overriding?

Comment: @vladon, I do not really now. It looks syntaxically similar to CRTP (see one of the comments), but it is not, since std::vector is not CRTP-aware.

Answer (score 2):

Things become miserable as soon as the class is recognized as a base class, only (due to an operator or a function taking the base class). Just do not do it. A sample try for a modifying/extending attempt might be std::string - there is none.