# How to inherit std::vector template in user-defined class template in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I am trying to inherit the `std::vector` class template into my `membvec` class template as `public`. And I want to use it as *e.g.* say `membvec<float> mymemb(10)` with the intention of creating my `membvec` variable `mymemb` containing `10` elements.

But I can't figure out how to write the **templatised declaration** of the `public` **inheritance**. What I am doing is the following, but all in vain.

```
template <typename T, template <typename T> class std::vector = std::vector<T>>
//error above: expected '>' before '::' token
class membvec: public std::vector<T>
{
    const membvec<T> operator-() const; // sorry the previous version was a typo 
    //error above: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
    ...
};
```

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector). Do you really need to inherit from `std::vector`?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to inherit from vector?  Normally just adding global free functions to extend its functionality works.

Comment: Yes, I want to feed it to another function which requires addition, subtraction, multiplication and division operators to be defined in addition to generic `std::vector` operations.

Comment: You're over-complicating things. The only template parameter you need is `T`. But I don't think you need public inheritance at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza, allegedly, OP wants other containers as well? The syntax would be `template <typename T, template <typename... > class container = std::vector<T>> class membvec : public container`

Comment: @SergeyA "I am trying to inherit the std::vector..." So I doubt that.

Comment: Wait wait! Could I get a solution for my particular case, and not in general? Well then things will be simpler for me to understand the syntax. In fact, I really don't  know all the nitty-gritty of the `std::vector` template parameters. These `container` things are confusing me. Any pointer would be of great help.

Comment: smql, in this case, you really don't need anything else but a single T, as @juanchopanza says. I thought, you want to be able to use other containers as well, but if it is set to be vector, all you need is `template <class T> class membvec : public std::vector<T>`

Comment: Well I started something with `template <class T>`. I will check it. Thanks. Seems like it will work.

Comment: This part is complete nonsense: `template <typename T> class std::vector = std::vector<T>` ... a template parameter named "std::vector" which is a std::vector ... wat? You don't need `std::vector` in the template parameter list at all, the only template parameter you need is `T`. If you want to derive from `std::vector<T>` then just do that, don't make it part of the template parameter list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the below, but seriously don't do it. If you ever pass your class as its parent `std::vector`, there is no virtual interface to allow your class to provide any benefit whatsoever. And if you *don't* need to substitute for a `std::vector` then there's no need to inherit from it. Prefer free function algorithms or containing the `std::vector` as a member in your class instead.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class membvec: public std::vector<T>
{
    // Don't need <T> in class scope, must return by value.
    membvec operator+() const;
};

int main()
{
    membvec<int> foo;
}
```

Comment: My typo for the `return by reference`. I just typed something before I ended up with this `declaration` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
#include <vector>                                                   

template <typename T, template <typename T, class Allocator> class Vec = std::vector>
class membvec: public Vec<T, std::allocator<T>>                                                                                             
{
public:
    // This is the signature in your question, but it's questionable.
    const membvec<T, Vec> &operator+(int x) const
    {
        // You obviously want to change this.
        return *this;
    }
};
```

You can then use it regularly:

```
int main()
{
    membvec<char> foo;
    foo + 3;
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza I completely agree. If you note, I wrote in the comment that it's the one in the question (and I just wanted to show how to get it building), but it's questionable.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that.