# Clang unable to find a friend function template of a templated class more than once if it's inside a namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I apologize for the title, but I wasn't able to think of anything better considering how peculiar this issue is.

I found this issue inside over a thousand-line long header, and eventually was able to narrow it down to the following code sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

namespace cpplinq
{
    template <typename T>
    struct IEnumerable : private std::vector<T>
    {
        template <typename ACont, typename U>
        friend IEnumerable<U> LINQ(ACont);      
    };

    template <typename ACont, typename T = typename std::decay<decltype(*(std::declval<typename std::remove_reference<ACont>::type>().begin()))>::type>
    IEnumerable<T> LINQ(ACont cont)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> ret;
        std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), [&ret](T val) {ret.push_back(val); });
        return ret;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto mvalue = cpplinq::LINQ(std::vector<int>{1,2}); // compiles
    auto mmvalue = cpplinq::LINQ(std::vector<int>{1,2}); // doesn't compile 
    auto mmmvalue = cpplinq::LINQ(std::vector<int>{1,2}); // doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Please ignore the function and struct names as they aren't relevant here.

When compiled with clang 3.4.1 or 4.0.0, the "mvalue" line compiles, and the two following lines don't, despite being syntactically identical.

https://godbolt.org/g/qaJzyQ - The version with only the "mvalue" line.
https://godbolt.org/g/T9DZek - The version with all three.

What's even more peculiar is that if you remove the "namespace cpplinq", and the associated braces, the entire thing compiles without a hitch, as shown here: https://godbolt.org/g/0Wl3jV

Comment: Of-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: Offtopic. The good or bad design of the class isn't the point here, it's the inconsistency in compiling it with clang.

Comment: @redspah, I have a feeling that `*xxx.begin()` is tried to be evaluated, which is impossible. May be you could try to `declval` the iterator instead?

Comment: @Incomputable I'm unsure of what are you asking me to do. Do you mean replacing the `*xxx.begin()` with `declval` inside the templated part or inside the function body? If it's the former then I can't see how it could be "declvaled" even more, if the latter then unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @redspah, I mean after stripping off reference, try to get `::iterator`, and declval that. Basically `decltype(*std::declval<typename std::decay<ACont>::type::iterator>())`. Trying that introduced enourmous error list.

Comment: Got it working. Replace `T` with this `typename T = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<typename std::decay<ACont>::type::iterator>())>::type`.

Comment: Clang appears to declare the `LINQ` friend function declaration without merging the default argument for `T` of the already existing declaration (the definition). Perhaps it is a mis-implementation of this rule: "If a friend function template declaration specifies a default template-argument, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function template in the translation unit.", which only applies if the friend function declaration gives the default argument. Note that if you call it with `::LINQ`, it also fails when you remove the namespace.

Comment: @Incomputable I don't think we're on the same page here. I just tried the edit you proposed and nothing changed: https://godbolt.org/g/DXs0jV
Besides, I'd rather not rely on anything more than `ACont` having `begin()` and `end()` defined.

Comment: That would explain why the first call works, because at that time, the friend function declaration wasn't instantiated yet.

Comment: @redspah, after reloading the file it stopped compiling ... Usually a type that has begin and end will have `iterator` type alias. My point is that doing anything after the declval call will try to evaluate it, which is the case with `*(std::declval<typename std::remove_reference<ACont>::type>().begin())`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That does sound like it's the issue, thanks. Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? If all else fails I'll just change the inheritance of std::vector to be public instead of private, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Incomputable Unfortunately, it only compiles on gcc. Try to compile it with clang 3.4.1 and flag "-std=c++11" instead.

Comment: @redspah you can make a LINQ_impl function and a non-friend wrapper LINQ that has the default argument, but the code is in LINQ_impl.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm very sorry, but I can't figure out how do to the thing you're just described. Would you mind quickly writing down the implementation of your idea?

Comment: @redspah http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c4b0e88ab2e9e4f

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Massive thanks for this. Now I get it, and shall use it in the full file.