# C++ Can you make an iterator of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator, template-classes

I'm working on a class project and for it for it we have to make a template class that is derived from vector and then be able to add and remove elements from it.

I thought I would make and iterator of the class since it is a vector I thought I should just be able to use "this" and create the iterator but "this" is a pointer so that didn't work.

If I try this:`vector<T>::iterator p;` I get plenty of errors so can I even do this or do I just need to find a different solution?

Comment: You should not inherit from `std::vector` as it does not have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not inherit from `std::vector` as it does not have a virtual destructor.  For more info see [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/).

If you want to use the `iterator` from `std::vector` you have to import it into your class' scope with the `using` directive.

```
#include <vector>

template < typename T >
class MyVector : std::vector<T>
{
public:
  using typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
};

int main()
{
  MyVector<double>::iterator p;
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer to "Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector" state "Actually, there is nothing wrong with public inheritance of std::vector.". Not quite a good example ;)