# Undefined reference in g++ 7 when inheriting from std::vector

Tags: c++, g++

Here is a piece of code which fails to compile under g++-7.2 and clang-5.0 and compiles perfectly under g++-5 (-std=c++11).

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Array : private std::vector<T> {
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Base;

    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Array<int> a((int*)nullptr, (int*)nullptr);
}
```

The error arises at the linking stage: `main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'std::allocator<int>::allocator()'`.

If I declare my array as `Array<int> a`, it compiles perfectly.

What's the problem here? As far as I understand, instantiation of template `Array<int>` enforces instantiation of `std::vector<int>`, which, in order, instantiates `std::allocator<int>`.

[Demo with g++-5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c793117ffb1c9158)

[Demo with g++-7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c9b7b462668cbcb)

P.S. I'm aware of possible pitfalls in inheriting from STL containers. Here inheritance is private, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357417/2159939) answer claims that it is allowed. Anyway, the question is not about whether it is a good practice or not.

P.P.S. I would be glad if you suggest a better title.

Comment: "In my case there are no additional data members, so it should not pose any problems." - wrong thinking.

Comment: OK, you're right, I'll make the inheritance private. This answer claims that it is allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357417/2159939. It still does not remove the error, and my question is NOT about inheriting from STL containers by itself.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug to me

Comment: And what should happen (if it would compile) when you pass two nullptr?

Comment: @manni66 I don't care about what happens at runtime, I just wanted to call a constructor from two int pointers (which exists), and passing nullptr-s is the simplest way to do it. It is a minimal example, not real code.

Comment: This compiles and links on g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
and Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)

Command line : g++ --std=c++14 -Wall -g main.cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change on semantics of inherited constructors in GCC7. However, you can compile your code using `-fno-new-inheriting-ctors` switch.

More information is in GCC7 changelog: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html and [P0136](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html).

Comment: That feeling when the changelog says 'Most uses should not need any changes' and you are affected somehow.