# Class derived from std::map does not compile on Visual C++ (but compiles on gcc and clang)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stdmap

I'm writing some container class that wraps std::map. A simplified version if it is:

```cpp
#include <map>

template <typename key_type, typename value_type>
class map2 : private std::map<key_type, value_type>
{
public:
    void update(const key_type& key, value_type value)
    {
        (*this)[key] = std::move(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    map2<int, int> m;
    m.update(1,4);
}
```

This code compiles just fine on gcc and clang, but on Visual C++ (I tested the 2015 version and whatever is used on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual ) it fails with:

```
source_file.cpp(16): error C2664: 'void map2<int,int>::update(const int &,std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int' to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'
        with
        [
            _Kty=int,
            _Ty=int
        ]
source_file.cpp(16): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64
```

So Visual C++ somehow assumes that the `value` parameter of map2::update() is of type `std::pair<key_type, value_type>` and not of `value_type`. But why is it doing that, while gcc and clang accept my code just fine?

Comment: I don't know why VC++ is doing it (although that compiler's name lookup rules have always been screwy), but the simple solution is not to name your template parameters the same as the typedefs from the base class.

Comment: fyi: this post addresses inheriting from `std::vector`, but I think most of it applies to `std::map` as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: This is fixed by setting the `/permissive-` command line switch

Comment: @Mgetz that's an option if you have control over the build environment. But for CI builds you're generally stuck with the compiler flags somebody else has set, and need to adjust your code to compile with those flags. So setting a command line switch is not a general solution to this problem.

Comment: @Dreamer true, I would suggest convincing them to go with `/permissive-` anyway as it helps enforce conformance with the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely what Visual C++ is **not** doing, and that's two-phase name lookup. Since there's only one phase of name lookup, it will have to look up `value_type` in that phase. And as a hack, VC++ then already looks into dependent base classes such as `std::map<key_type, value_type>` here.

This incorrectly finds `std::map<K, V>::value_type`, a typedef for `pair<K,V>`. This explains the VC++ error message.

Workaround: Disambiguate the argument name in `map2` yourself.

Comment: Agreed - this sounds plausible. Suggest using completely different names. Probably a good idea anyway tbh

Comment: If this is the case then VS2017 should potentially compile this code in `/permissive-` and C++17 mode as that is supposed to allegedly support two phase. Edit [Confirmed](https://godbolt.org/g/V5gtdY)