# How to create a class which inheritates from std::vector

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, stdvector

I need to inherit all functions from `std::vector` and I want to *overload operators* to make a complete `matrix` class.
There is not too much documentation on this topic.

**Matriz.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Matriz:vector<T>
{
public:
    using vector<T>::vector;
private:
}
```

**Matriz.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Matriz<int> dani;
    dani.push_back(2); //Here is the error and I don`t know what it happens
}
```

When I want to initialize it, I got an error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2247   'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back' not accessible because 'Matriz<int>' uses 'private' to inherit from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do this

Comment: First, be careful when inheriting from standard containers, they are not intended for that. Second, you have `private` inheritance.

Comment: I don't think inheriting privately from vector is that much of a problem. Regarding your question, could you be more specific about the problem you have? The error message gives you a pretty good indication of the problem.

Comment: try `class Matriz: public vector<T>`

Comment: Check out this question on whether inheriting from `std::vector` is a good idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Matriz: public std::vector<T>
{
public:
   using std::vector<T>::vector;

private:
};

int main()
{
   Matriz<int> dani;
   dani.push_back(2);
   dani.push_back(3);

   for(const auto& it: dani)
      std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Inherit from vector class is a mistake

It is very difficult and produces a lot of errors as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector).
I have made a class which has a vector and inlcudes:

- **template**
- **operator overloading**
- **matrix operations**

LINK : [vector.h](https://github.com/dani2442/Vector/blob/master/Vector/Vector.h)

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int);
    Vector(int, int);

    ~Vector();

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> v;

    bool Check_Size() ;
    template<typename T1> bool Check_Size(std::vector<T1>&) ;
    template<typename T1> bool Check_Size_Fast(std::vector<T1>&);

    void Print();

    void Transponse();

    void Inverse();
    void Inverse2();
    void Inverse3();


    template<class T,class Q>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator* (const Q , Vector<T> );
    template<class T,class Q>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator* (Vector<T> , const Q );
    template<class T>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator*(Vector<T>& , Vector<T>&);
    template<typename T>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator+(Vector<T> &, Vector<T> &);
    template<typename T>
    friend std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator-(Vector<T> &, Vector<T> &);



    Vector<T>& operator = (const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
    {
        this->v = v;
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& operator +=( Vector<T>&v) {
        return v + (*this);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& operator -=(Vector<T>&v) {
        return v - (*this);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<T>>& operator *=(Vector<T>&v) {
        return v * (*this);
    }


private:

    void Recursive_Check(std::vector<T>&);

};
```