# How do I return a Generic Vector Iterator from an Inline Template method?

Tags: c++, generics, vector, iterator, return-type

OK. As the question states I have an Inline Template method that returns an Iterator to a generic vector.

note: I know I should change the implementation to std::find, but that's not the problem I'm facing.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class List : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();

    bool Contains(T object);

    void Remove(const T& object);

private:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;

    typename std::vector<T>::iterator IteratorOf(const T& object);
};


template<typename T>
inline typename std::vector<T>::iterator List<T>::IteratorOf(const T& 
object)
{
    if (this->empty())
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        for (typename std::vector<T*>::iterator iter = this->begin();
          iter != this->end();                                       
          iter++)
        {
        if (*object == *iter)
            return iter;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

This throws a myriad of compiler errors when I try and run it.

I seem to have tried everything however this method simply is not liked.

Beginning to wonder if there's a problem with returning generic iterators.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to derive from `std::vector`.  Your question is also showing all the earmarks of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm attempting to provide a wrapper for a vector that provides a few extension methods. Checking if an element exists within the vector, and removing an element, based on value.

Is it a better idea to have this vector as a member variable of the List class I am creating?

Comment: Before doing this, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector).  The vector should be a member.  Second, why are you *not* using the algorithm functions such as `std::find` and use `auto` to simplify things?  Why create busy work for yourself when there is no need to?

Comment: Why are you trying to return `nullptr` as if it were a `std::vector` iterator?  They are sometimes pointers (depending on the implementation), but rarely null.

Comment: @DavisHerring It was a decision scoped only within the class that nullptr from that method would represent an empty list/unfound element. std::find is better and I've since moved onto that. I've answered this question with the solution that I found that caused this problem/question.

Comment: @Natalo77: But you shouldn’t assume that `nullptr` is usable as a `vector` iterator—even as a “not found” value.

Comment: @DavisHerring Other methods would check for the variable being returned into for nullptr before using. However, I understand the issues the point you raise causes, but have since moved onto `std::find` and this wasn't causing the error in the question.

Comment: @Natalo77: But it might be a type error (*i.e.*, not compile) to use that value even long enough to check it!

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah. A second look may have spotted a mistake in my original post. Whilst faffing about to try and resolve my error, I must have removed the `*` from the return value of `std::vector<T>::iterator`

Comment: @Natalo77: But then you can’t return `iter` (except by some thoroughly clumsy method like making it `static` or usung `new` to keep (a copy of) it alive).

Comment: @DavisHerring I know, my implementation was dogshite xD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual answer to this myriad of compiler errors is one that is completely unrelated to this specific problem.

**You cannot define templated methods outside of the header file**

Visual Studio will throw a whole HEAP of errors, leading you down a rabbit hole away from what is a relatively simple issue to fix.