# Define destructor of class X which inherits from a vector of pointers to object Y and has array of pointers to Z

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

So I'll try to be as clear as possible about this. Say we have the following:

```
class X : protected vector<objectY*> 
{
private:
objectZ** array;
unsigned size;
unsigned capacity;

public:
X():size(0), capacity(0), array(new objectZ*[100]){}
X(const objectX& o); // to be defined later 
X& operator=(const X& x); //defined later
~X(){ delete [] array; clear(); } <--- is this correct, or it produces memory leak?
void add(objectZ* o); // used to add objects to array

}
```

Now let's say we already defined class Y and Z with all the basic stuff we need for the above code to compile. My question is the following:
Is the destructor correct? Does my code have memory leak?

Say I go to main() and I do this:

```
objectZ* o1 = new objectZ();
objectX* x1 = new objectX();

x1->add(o1);

 delete o1; // to avoid memory leak;
return 0; // end of main.
```

Since I'm mostly adding stuff to objectX's array from main, and most likely using polymorphism, like

```
 objectZ* ok = new objectK(); // where k is derived from Z
 x1->add(ok);
```

how do I define properly the destructor of class X without having memory leaks, and considering it also inherits from a vector of pointers to another objectY, do I need to cycle the vector 1 by 1 element and call delete on it, and clear() at the end or is clear() enough? Do i cycle array and call delete on it's elements too? My thoughts are that since I'm not allocating memory from within class X, I don't need to deallocate it either. I only need to delete [] array, and possibly clear() the inherited vector.

Comment: `std::vector` is [not designed/intended to be derived from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/) (none of the standard library containers are). And why are you not using a `std:vector` for the `objectZ*` array?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the destructor correct? Does my code have memory leak?

Possibly.  If `X` is supposed to take ownership of the `objectZ` objects in its array, then it needs to free those objects before then freeing the array itself, otherwise they are leaked.

On a side note, your `main()` example is leaking the `x1` object. It is not clear whether you meant to call `delete x1` instead of `delete o1`, or whether `x1->add(o1)` is supposed to take ownership of `o1` or not.

> how do I define properly the destructor of class X without having memory leaks

By not doing manual memory management in the first place.  Make proper use of smart pointers, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, and let them handle the memory management for you.

> considering it also inherits from a vector of pointers to another objectY, do I need to cycle the vector 1 by 1 element and call delete on it

Quite likely, yes.  It really depends on the ownership model that `X` employs.  If `X` takes ownership of the `objectY` and `objectZ` objects, then it is responsible for freeing them.  Otherwise, if it does not take ownership, then it is not responsible for freeing them.

> and clear() at the end or is clear() enough?

For an array of raw pointers, `clear()` simply removes the pointers from the array, it does not free the objects being pointed at.  An array of smart pointers, on the other hand, will free the objects when the smart pointers are removed from the array.

> My thoughts are that since I'm not allocating memory from within class X, I don't need to deallocate it either.

Any object allocated with `new` must be freed with `delete`.  Whether that needs to happen inside of `X` or not will depend on `X`'s particular ownership model.

Comment: Why would you need to `clear()` before `delete[]`ing an unrelated pointer? In fact, the `clear()` is completely redundant anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I reworded that part of my answer

Comment: So does clear() call the destructor of all objectY pointers contained in the vector? 
Or I should do something like:
    for(int i=0; i<size(); i++) delete (*this)[i]

Comment: @Roben "*does clear() call the destructor of all objectY pointers contained in the vector?*" - No. I covered that in my answer. "*I should do something like: `for(int i=0; i<size(); i++) delete (*this)[i]`*" - if `X` is meant to take ownership of the `objectY` objects, then yes.  Same with the `objectZ` objects. Better to use `std::unique_ptr<objectY>` and `std::unique_ptr<objectZ>` instead of `objectY*` and `objectZ*`, respectively.

Comment: My bad, saw the edited answer after commenting.

Also, if by `x` taking ownership of `objectY` you mean I add objects to the vector using `new` as in: `push_back(new objectY*())` then no `x` doesnt take ownership of `objectY`, I simply `push_back(objectY* pointer)` which is passed as a parameter to the add function. Same thing for `array`. So no ownership is taken in that sense, do I still have to call delete on all objects contained in the vector, and all objects contained in `array` and use `clear()` and `delete [] array` respectively?

Comment: @Roben <sigh> No, that is not what I mean by ownership. But in any case, if `X` DOES NOT take ownership of the objects added to its vector/array, then it MUST NOT call `delete` on them, only call `delete[]` on the array and `clear()` on the vector. On the other hand, if `X` DOES NOT take ownership, you must ensure that `X` is destroyed BEFORE the objects in its array/vector are destroyed, otherwise it will be holding dangling pointers to invalid memory. It would really help if you fix your question to provide better examples of what exactly you are trying to accomplish with `X`

Comment: @Roben from C++11 onwards, storing of raw pointers implies observation only, not ownership. Storing of smart pointers implies ownership.

Comment: Got it. So simply put, since I allocate memory in `main()`, using `new` to create the `Y` and `Z`, and store a pointer to those objects in `X`, `X object` does NOT own those pointers since they're raw pointers and thus it's not responsible for freeing the memory.

So `~X(){ delete [] array; clear(); }` would be the correct implementation in this case. Also referring to what you said earlier, does `clear()` and `delete[] order `matter in unrelated pointers? Is `clear()` necessary or I can just do `delete[] array` and be done with the dtor?

Comment: @Roben You need to decide what your ownership model is. Do you want `X` to own the `objectY` and `objectZ` objects, or just point to objects that are owned by code outside of `X`? You have not said one way or the other what you actually want. As for `clear()`, it is not required in `X`'s destructor since the inherited `vector`'s destructor will be called after `~X()` exits, thus clearing the inherited `vector` for you. But I strongly suggest you replace your `objectZ*` array with a `std::vector` then you don't have to worry about calling `delete[]` on the array at all.