# C++ How to implement only one constructor of a multiple inheritance class

Tags: c++

I got classes below:

```
enum class Kind {
  Monday,
  Tuesday,
};

class Day {
 public:
  Day(Kind kind) : kind_(kind) {}
 private:
  Kind kind_;
};

class Tuesday : public Day, public std::vector<int> {
 public:
  Tuesday(...) : std::vector<int>(...), Day(Kind::Tuesday) {}
};
```

As you can see, even the Tuesday class inherit from Day, it calls `Day(Kind::Tuesday)`, so the constructor forms of `Tuesday` should be the same with `std::vector<int>`

But even the constructor form is the same, I have to re-write all the constructors to match the constructors of `std::vector<int>`, and append `Day(Kind::Tuesday)` to the end of each constructor.

All I want is to use `Tuesday` as a vector. So I just curious if there's an easy way to do this?

Comment: " I have to re-write all the constructors" not really clear. There is only a single constructor for `Tuesday` in your code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I mean there's a lot of constructors in `std::vector<int>`, I have to create constructors of `Tuesday` to match each of the constructors in `std::vector<int>`

Comment: just pick the constructor you like and use it. Why do you think you have to provide all of them? Maybe your question is more clear if you show at least a second constructor. And please replace the `...` with real code

Comment: Deriving from `std::vector` is potentially a bad idea.

Comment: @reavenisadesk Why not just have one c'tor that takes an `std::vector` as an r-value reference? I.e. the user can construct it however they want.

Comment: @DeiDei https://stackoverflow.com/q/4353203

Comment: This whole example looks like a bad idea. Why is `Tuesday` a class?

Comment: @Caleth it’s just an example which is similar to my current problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variadic template constructor:

```
template <typename... Types>
Tuesday(Types... args) : std::vector<int>(args...), Day(Kind::Tuesday) {}
```