# CPP: Matrix Destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

For the following `mymatrix` class definition, why don't I need the commented parts of the destructor? Don't we need to delete what the a pointer points to as well? Or is it because we deleted all the meaningful data that we don't need these (commented-out) parts of the destructor?

```
template<typename T> 
class mymatrix
 {
 private:
   struct ROW
   {
     T*  Cols;     // dynamic array of column elements
     int NumCols;  // total # of columns (0..NumCols-1)
   }; 

  ROW* Rows;     // dynamic array of ROWs
  int  NumRows;  // total # of rows (0..NumRows-1) 
}
```

Destructor:

```
virtual ~mymatrix()
{
for(int r=0;r<numRows;r++)
{
    for(int c=0;c<Rows[r].NumCols;c++)
    {
        delete Rows[r].Cols[c];
    }
    // delete Rows[r];
}
// delete Rows;
}
```

Constructor:

```
  mymatrix(int R, int C)
  {
    if (R < 1)
      throw invalid_argument("mymatrix::constructor: # of rows");
    if (C < 1)
      throw invalid_argument("mymatrix::constructor: # of cols");

    Rows = new ROW[R];  // an array with R ROW structs:
    NumRows = R;
    //intialize each row to C columns
    for(int r=0;r<R;r++){
        Rows[r].Cols=new T[C];
        Rows[r].NumCols=C;

        //initialize elements to their default value
        for(int c=0;c<Rows[r].NumCols;c++){
            Rows[r].Cols[c]=T{}; // default value for type T;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you know you don't need the commented code?

Comment: Please never use `new/delete` in `C++`!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If you never call `new` in `mymatrix` you should also not call `delete`. Your comments say "dynamic array" but both `Cols` and `ROW` are just pointers. Use `std::vector` if you want dynamic arrays

Comment: We have no idea until you show us where you use `new`. For every call to new there should be a corresponding call to delete (no more/no less). Note: That is still not all you need to do but that is all you asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use array-delete syntax because you are deleting arrays, not single objects:

`delete[] Rows[r].Cols`

...

`delete[] Rows`

Edit: I originally simply included the correct `delete[]` operator usage and left everything unchanged in my original example for brevity, but as @idclev463035818 pointed out, whenever you define your own destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator (especially when they involve dynamic memory allocation), you almost always need to have all three. Almost never do you want any one without the others because if you have raw pointers in your object, then they will be shallow-copied to the new objects being instantiated. Then later on, the destructors for each of these objects will be called and attempt to delete the same portions of memory multiple times, which is a major error. I've added these to the code example and make use of them in new tests in the `main` function.

---

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class mymatrix
{
public:
    struct ROW
    {
        T*  Cols;     // dynamic array of column elements
        int NumCols;  // total # of columns (0..NumCols-1)
    };

    ROW* Rows;     // dynamic array of ROWs
    int  NumRows;  // total # of rows (0..NumRows-1) 
public:
    mymatrix(int R, int C)
    {
        init(R, C);
    }

    void init(int R, int C) {
        if (R < 1)
            throw "";//throw invalid_argument("mymatrix::constructor: # of rows");
        if (C < 1)
            throw "";//invalid_argument("mymatrix::constructor: # of cols");

        Rows = new ROW[R];  // an array with R ROW structs:
        NumRows = R;
        //intialize each row to C columns
        for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
            Rows[r].Cols = new T[C];
            Rows[r].NumCols = C;

            //initialize elements to their default value
            for (int c = 0; c < Rows[r].NumCols; c++) {
                Rows[r].Cols[c] = T{}; // default value for type T;
            }
        }
    }

    mymatrix(const mymatrix& other) : mymatrix(other.NumRows, other.Rows[0].NumCols) {
        for (int r = 0; r < NumRows; ++r) {
            ROW& thisRow = Rows[r];
            ROW& otherRow = other.Rows[r];
            for (int c = 0; c < thisRow.NumCols; ++c) {
                thisRow.Cols[c] = otherRow.Cols[c];
            }
        }
    }

    mymatrix& operator=(const mymatrix& other) {
        if (other.NumRows != NumRows || other.Rows[0].NumCols != Rows[0].NumCols) {
            clear();
            init(other.NumRows, other.Rows[0].NumCols);
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < NumRows; ++r) {
            ROW& thisRow = Rows[r];
            ROW& otherRow = other.Rows[r];
            for (int c = 0; c < thisRow.NumCols; ++c) {
                thisRow.Cols[c] = otherRow.Cols[c];
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (int r = 0; r < NumRows; r++)
        {
            delete[] Rows[r].Cols;
        }
        delete[] Rows;

        Rows = NULL;
        NumRows = 0;
    }

    virtual ~mymatrix()
    {
        clear();
    }

};

int main() {
    mymatrix<int> mat(5, 5);
    mat.Rows[0].Cols[2] = 5;

    mymatrix<int> matClone(mat);
    cout << matClone.Rows[0].Cols[2] << endl;

    matClone.Rows[0].Cols[1] = 8;

    cout << mat.Rows[0].Cols[1] << endl;

    mat = matClone;

    cout << mat.Rows[0].Cols[1] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They told us that they are using dynamic arrays. I have no option but to take their word for it until they post more information

Comment: You do have the option to ask for clarifying information before posting an answer.

Comment: @Alex, So I would leave the first delete statement and uncomment and change the last two?

Comment: @thegoodhunter-9115 Only uncomment the last line. Refresh and check my current edit

Comment: So just: 
virtual ~mymatrix()
{
for(int r=0;r<numRows;r++)
{
    delete[] Rows[r].Cols;
}
delete[] Rows;
}

Comment: @thegoodhunter-9115 Yes that's correct! I'll also update my answer with a full working example

Comment: the code you posted does not respect the rule of 0/3/5. A simple line `auto mat2 = mat;` will cause big trouble

Comment: As user @idclev463035818 pointed out, there's a common rules in C++ that if you define your own copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or destructor, then you almost always need to define all three. I've defined all three in my updated example and added test uses of these in the main function. This will properly handle memory when copying your matrix.

Answer (score -3):

I'm telling this every time I see the usage of `new/delete` in `C++`.

Please don't use `new/delete` in `C++`!

Here is a minimal example of how to create a matrix which will allocate and delete itself without any manual memory allocations.

```
#include <vector>

class Matrix : public std::vector<std::vector<int>> {
public:
  Matrix(size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
      : std::vector<std::vector<int>>(numRows, std::vector<int>(numCols, 0)) {}
  size_t numRows() const { return size(); }
  size_t numCols() const { return front().size(); }
};

int main() {
  auto m = Matrix(5, 4);
  return m[4][3];
}
```

Comment: They need to know how to use new/delete correctly if they are going to use C++

Comment: @Alex only if you are going to develop an operating system or boost/STL library. In all other cases, you don't need it. In the worst case `std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr` should be used.

Comment: inheriting publicly from `std::vector` is a bad idea. `std::vector` is not a polymorphic type

Comment: @idclev463035818 absolutely fine in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: well I dont agree with the accepted answer on that question, because it is just to easy to use it wrong for little to zero benefit

Comment: you replace one bad practice with a different one

Comment: make sure to also read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357417/4117728

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've read all the answers. And accepted one is the best.