# Why the inheritance of a class with non-virtual destructor is not a good thing even if the derived class adds no members?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357417/9140652) answer:

> In particular, you are not allowed to delete a `std::vector<T>*` that
>   actually points at a derived object (even if the derived class adds no
>   members), yet the compiler generally can't warn you about it.

I understand that virtual destructor is needed if the object will be deleted through a base pointer. That's to let each class destroy it's members (at least I think so). But if the class don't have any members in itself, then why it shouldn't be deleted through the base pointer?

And also, how do I force some class to be accessed only through a pointer with it's type and not with one of the bases? will this make it normal to inherit from a class with a non-virtual destructor?

Comment: because the standard says so. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: That very answer provides a link to cppreference which states "If expression evaluates to a pointer to a base class subobject of the object that was allocated with new, the destructor of the base class must be virtual, otherwise the behavior is undefined." There is your answer.

Comment: I can't think of a way to ensure checking in your *And also*. but it gets me thinking, "Is inheritance the right solution for this questioner's problem? Perhaps I should point them at [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)"

Comment: The (perhaps slightly not-what-you-had-in-mind) answer to your last question is: private inheritance.