# Custom vector container using STL vector

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I have a code where vector is defined like this

`typedef std::vector<double> my_vec`

and a matrix as

`typedef std::vector<my_vec> matrix`

Would it be possible to replace this definitions with a custom class which preserves all the features of the STL vector (does not break existing  code) but can also be extended with new members.

In fact what I'm looking for is to simply add a bool flag to every vector.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to inherit from `std::vector`. Relevant question: [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4353203/580083).

Comment: Refactor tools :). You might also consider transforming the old type into your new one with added `bool`, especially if none of the old code cares about the extra member.

Comment: Thanks for tips. I just gave it a try and it... almost works. Looks like I can't push back vector to matrix. I can post custom vector class code if you need it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It all works fine. The problem was elsewhere. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tips I received, here is the custom class I have created.

```
 template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                    
 class fp_vec : public std::vector<T> {                                                                                                                                                                   
     public:                                                                                                                                                                                              
         using std::vector<T>::vector;                                                                                                                                                                    
         bool n = false;                                                                                                                                                                         
 };
```

and the typedefs

```
typedef fp_vec<double> my_vec
typedef fp_vec<my_vec> matrix
```

I understand this is not ideal as `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor so dynamic allocation is serious no no here.