# How to put a custom container I've created into library so it could be initialized like any other container (like std::vector for instance)?

Tags: c++, oop, file-structure

Below is the code of header files for my container which is a heterogeneous vector.

```
// HVElemVar.hh 
#pragma once
#include <variant>
// contains headers of types that will be stored in the container
#include <Type1.hh>
#include <Type2.hh>    

using myVariant = std::variant<Type1, Type2>;


// HVElem.hh
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <HVElemVar.hh>

class HVElem
{
public:
    HVElem( myVariant newData );
    ~HVElem();
    myVariant getData();
private:
    myVariant data;
};


// HVector.hh
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <HVElem.hh>


class HVector: public std::vector<HVElem>
{
public:
    HVector();
    void push(myVariant newData);
    void show();
};
```

In this code, I use `HVElemVar.hh` to declare types stored inside each `HVElem` of `HVector`. The issue is that I might need multiple `HVector`'s with a different set of types in the same program. Basically I want to be able to do this:

```
std::vector<Type1> v1;
HVector<Type1, Type2> v2; // just  like with normal std::vector  
HVector<Type3, Type4> v3; // another HVector but with different types inside
```

1. How can I make `HVector` able to be initialized like normal `std::vector`?
2. Can I put `myVariant` inside `HVElem` and change it's value when class is contructed?

Comment: Worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector

Comment: Your `HVector` class is not templated, so you cannot use it like a template... You simply do `HVector v2;`.

Comment: It seems like you would benefit from reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). You are looking for templates.