# Inheriting from standard library containers results in slicing

Tags: c++, inheritance, containers

I came across an old [SO post about inheriting from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector). One of the comments made was unclear to me, why does slicing occur when you inherit from a standard library container and use a pointer/reference to the base?

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:21),source:%27%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Aclass+MyVec+:+public+vector%3Cint%3E%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+printTypeBase(vector%3Cint%3E%26+vecObj)%0A%7B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+%22base+parameter+ref:+%22+%3C%3C+typeid(vecObj).name()+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+printTypeDerived(MyVec%26+vecObj)%0A%7B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+%22derived+parameter+ref:+%22+%3C%3C+typeid(vecObj).name()+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+myVec+%3D+MyVec%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++printTypeBase(myVec)%3B%0A++++printTypeDerived(myVec)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:39.32114882506527,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1001,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.1+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:60.67885117493472,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyVec : public vector<int>
{};

void printTypeBase(vector<int>& vecObj)
{
    cout << "base parameter ref: " << typeid(vecObj).name() << endl;
}

void printTypeDerived(MyVec& vecObj)
{
    cout << "derived parameter ref: " << typeid(vecObj).name() << endl;
}


int main()
{
    auto myVec = MyVec{};

    printTypeBase(myVec);
    printTypeDerived(myVec);
}
```

Outputs:

> base parameter ref: St6vectorIiSaIiEE

> derived parameter ref: 5MyVec

---

When I try to dynamic_cast inside `printTypeBase` :

```
auto temp = dynamic_cast<MyVec&>(vecObj);
```

I get a clarifying error message:

> error: 'std::vector<int, std::allocator >' is not polymorphic

---

In retrospect, my question should have been why is `std::vector` not a polymorphic type?

Comment: There is no slicing taking place here, as a result of using a pointer to a reference. Replace `std::vector<int>` by `class foo` everywhere, and you'll get the same results.

Comment: Types in C++ are not dynamic, they are fixed and static. In the `printTypeBase` function the `vecObj` variable is a reference to `vector<int>`, the compiler can't change that.

Comment: That's not what slicing is. `MyVec` is an empty derived class. There's nothing in it that can be sliced. If you want to see slicing, then add a data member, like an `int` for example, and then copy the object through a `vector<int>&`. Then you get slicing of the `int` member because `vector<int>::operator=` knows nothing about that `int` member.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [when I replace vector<int> with a foo class](https://godbolt.org/z/a7WbG6) which has the virtual function in it, I get the ""correct"" behaviour, typeid prints "MyVec" for both functions. I understand now the point about non-polymorphic types, so this makes sense.

Comment: And even with a virtual function, still no slicing takes place. It only takes place when the base class is ***copied***. No copying takes place. `typeid` is not an indication of object slicing taking place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard library containers have no virtual methods and also no virtual destructor. They completely lack a vtable.

Your code fails to test what you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing isn't occurring here, however, for references to types that are not polymorphic (such as classes with no virtual methods), `typeid` resolves to the static type information of the argument, not the dynamic type.

Answer (score 1):

> why does slicing occur

There is no slicing in your example. There is nothing in particular about standard library containers that causes slicing more than inheriting from any other type.

> base parameter ref: St6vectorIiSaIiEE

> error: 'std::vector<int, std::allocator >' is not polymorphic

The latter error explains the result of the `typeid`. Vector is not a polymorphic type. This is because it has no virtual functions. `dynamic_cast` is allowed only for polymorphic types, and `typeid` resolves to the dynamic type only in case of reference to polymorphic type.