# Only allow a C++ vector to grow when resizing

Tags: c++, vector, resize

Is there an alternative to `resize()` of an `std::vector`, which only allows the increase the size of the vector

```
std::vector v;
v.resize(10);
v.resize(5);
```

--> `v.size() == 5`, but I like its length to stay at `10` and moreover I like its data not to be (potentially) deleted.

I could use

```
std::vector v;
v.resize(std::max(v.size(),10));
v.resize(std::max(v.size(),5));
```

This is a bit ugly. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: This would be strange.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve. Familiarize yourself with the difference betweet the size and the capacity of a vector.

Comment: @MadScientist `reserve` does not fit the request.

Comment: You can create a function `myresize(v, 5);`

Comment: If the function doesn't actually resize, it should not be exposed to users of the class as `resize` since that goes against what people expect from a `resize` function.  I suggest using a better name for it, like `set_minimum_size` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a strange request. It would be interesting to know why you want this infinitely expanding vector. One solution (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357417/1294207)) would be to inherit from `std::vector` privately and implement your own resize, ie something like:

```
template <class T> // Can also forward the allocator if you want
class InfiniteResizeVector: private std::vector<T> 
// The private is very important, std::vector has no virtual destructor, so you 
// cannot allow someone to reference it polymorphically. 
{
public:
    using vector::push_back;
    using vector::operator[];
    ... // For all the functions you need
    void resize(size_t new_size) {
       vector::resize(std::max(size(),new_size));
    }
};
```

Usage would then just be `v.resize(5);` like you asked for. **Make sure you read some of the other answers from the link above**. This is a very unusual thing to do, unless this is something you will use all the time it is certainly not worth making your own independent type.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The OP specifically asks for the `resize` function to do this. I agree this is not ideal, but having said that, the whole point behind doing this is probably something that is either for learning or should be re-thought.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Great!

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic Mr Fox offers to solve this problem through inheritance and rewriting, but it's possible to solve this problem through <del>combination</del> composition, but it's probably a little more troublesome, and here's my example.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class OnlyGrowVector {
public:
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

    void push_back(T&& t)
    {
        m_vector.push_back(std::forward<T>(t));
    }

    T& operator[](size_type idx)
    {
        return m_vector[idx];
    }
... // for what you need
    void resize(size_type size)
    {
        m_vector.resize(std::max(m_vector.size(), size));
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_vector;
};
```

Comment: So what you are looking for is `composition` not combination, and it is a good way to solve this, but there is lots of boiler plate to expose normal vector things.