# but can I initialize that vector with a size and value in a hashmap (unordered_map)?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

So, I can very easily initialize a hashmap from int to vector...
But can I initialize that vector with a size and maybe default values ??

For example : `vector<int> a(2,0)` <--Size and values are initialized ....
So is there something for `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>`

Comment: What's the expect value for `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>`

Comment: Something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/scq6Woea7 ?

Comment: Another (more explicit) option: https://godbolt.org/z/a73v3Edd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around the vector like this:

```
struct DefaultSizedVector{
    DefaultSizedVector() : data{2, 0} {}
    vector<int> data;
};
```

Then the map type would be `unordered_map<int, DefaultSizedVector>` so then (by accessing the `.data` member) it would act like a vector except have a default size.

You could also have `DefaultSizedVector` inherit directly from `vector<int>` so that it would behave exactly like a vector, but you'd have to be careful that the usage of `DefaultSizedVector` is fairly constrained for reasons pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector).