# C++ Create class that inherits a Vector

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector

I would like to know if I can create a class that inherits a vector that contains vectors (2d) and can write my own methods.

```
using matrix = vector<vector<float>>;

class MyClass: public matrix;

...

MyClass m;

m = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}

m.randomize(); // my method
m.pop_back() //class vector method
```

Comment: Why not have just a class with the matrix as an attribute?

Comment: The `std::` collections are not designed to be inherited from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector)

Comment: @RichardCritten _"The std:: collections are not designed to be inherited from"_ That's not exactly true. They don't have `virtual` destructors which means they can't be deleted polymorphically from a base pointer; but there is nothing that prohibits them being inherited from. Even the answers on the linked question indicate the same. I'm not suggesting inheriting is good advice in this case; just that stating they are "not designed to be inherited from" is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if I can create a class that inherits a vector that contains vectors (2d) and can write my own methods

Yes, nothing prohibits this although it's generally recommended to use composition instead. One reason why it's not recommended is that the standard containers destructor is not `virtual` so deleting objects though base class pointers doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but that’s not what you want. Why should `MyClass` have a `push_back` method which can be used to make the matrix non-square? Why should its `resize` method set the number of rows but not the number of columns? Inheriting from a non-abstract class is almost never a good idea, compared to either composition or refactoring.