# Inherit from boost::matrix

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to inherit from `boost::matrix` to enrich with some methods. I started with this :

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

class MyMatrix : public matrix<double>
{
public:
    MyMatrix() : matrix<double>(0, 0) {}

    MyMatrix(int size1, int size2) : matrix<double>(size1, size2) {}

    MyMatrix(MyMatrix& mat) : matrix<double>(mat) {}

    MyMatrix(matrix<double>& mat) : matrix<double>(mat) {}

    MyMatrix& operator=(const MyMatrix& otherMatrix)
    {
        (*this) = otherMatrix;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

that allows me do to stuff like:

```
MyMatrix matA(3, 3);
MyMatrix matB(3, 3);
MyMatrix matC(matA);
```

but I may missed something because I am not able do to:

```
MyMatrix matD(matA * 2);
MyMatrix matE(matA + matB);
```

that causes:

```
error: conversion from 'boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_binary_traits<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>, boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>, boost::numeric::ublas::scalar_plus<double, double> >::result_type {aka boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_binary<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>, boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>, boost::numeric::ublas::scalar_plus<double, double> >}' to non-scalar type 'MyMatrix' requested
```

How can I use the methods from `boost::matrix` without redefining all of them inside `MyMatrix` ?

Comment: Did you verify that the class you want to inherit from has a virtual destructor? It's usually best to just write some free functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector)

Comment: Not sure if it's getting the intended effect across, as the top and accepted answer says to just do it. I feel like that's horrible advice.

Comment: I don't now much about `boost::numeric::ublas`. Can you please tell us what you want to add to it? You don't need any of those functions to make the example code work.

Comment: I would like to add some user defined methods to get (for example, but not only) minimum, maximum, mean, standard deviation of the values inside the matrix.

Comment: @dagnic Ok, then it should be simple. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of your additions to make this work:

```
MyMatrix matA(3, 3);
MyMatrix matB(3, 3);
MyMatrix matC(matA);

MyMatrix matD(matA * 2);
MyMatrix matE(matA + matB);
```

You only need to bring the `boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>` constructors and assignment operators into your derived class:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

class MyMatrix : public boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> {
public:
    using matrix<double>::matrix;    // use the constructors already defined
    using matrix<double>::operator=; // and the operator=s already defined

    // put your other additions here (except those you had in the question)
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjjz95fEb)